# How to access test method annotations from a TestExecutionListener

Tags: junit5, junit5-extension-model

I'm trying to port [Test Management For Jira JUnit Integration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.adaptavist/tm4j-junit-integration/1.0.0) to JUnit5. This module generates a JSON report of the test run and associates the results with Jira tickets by using annotations on the test methods, [example](https://www.adaptavist.com/doco/display/KT/Annotating+Test+Cases).

From the TestExecutionListener I'm not sure what the best approach to retrieve the TestCase annotation is.

I looked at Reflection using the TestIdentifier.getSource and doing manipulations to rebuild the method signature and extracting the annotation from there but the approach felt clumsy.

I came across this post [Allow extensions to register TestExecutionListeners](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/462#issuecomment-282856625) which proposed the following:

> Proposal: Have your extension publish the WebDriver bean's session id, e.g.

```
String sessionId = ...;
extensionContext.publishReportEntry("webDriverSessionId", sessionId)
```

> In your TestExecutionListener, implement reportingEntryPublished and store it in a Map with the TestIdentifier as a key. In executionFinished report the test outcome along with the value from this Map.

This approach looks promising but I want to make sure there isn't another way that doesn't require both an extension and a test execution listener. Is there a way to retrieve test method annotation information directly in the TestExecutionListener?

Comment: If you don't have a concrete need for implementing `TestExecutionListener`, you can implement the `TestWatcher` extension API for JUnit Jupiter and register that extension either via your custom annotation (i.e., meta-annotated with `@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)` or via the global registration mechanism. In your custom `TestWatcher` extension, you can access the current test method via the `ExtensionContext` and then look up your annotation on the method.

Comment: @SamBrannen I have a working solution using the method you described above and I do require the TestExecutionListener to write the report to file on testPlanExecutionFinished. I only need the Extension to capture the value associated with my annotation. I'm now trying to extend this to support ParameterizedTest I looked at getting the value from the parameters but ran into [Introduce extension API for accessing arguments passed to tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1139). I'm now trying to use TestReporter to publish the TestCaseKey in the test definition.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track!

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with accessing the parameters (`java.lang.reflect.Parameter`) for a `@ParameterizedTest`. That should work the same as for any method (`@Test`, etc.). Or do you really need to access the physical runtime _arguments_ passed to the method?

Comment: @SamBrannen sorry for the delay in my response, I appreciate you taking the time. I created this [gitproject](https://github.com/alexandre-senecal/tm4j_junit5) which demonstrates what I'm looking to accomplish and were I fall short.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can't get test annotation from `TestExecutionListener` but instead you can implement `TestWatcher` or e.g `AfterEachCallback` and get custom annotation value like that:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterEachCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestWatcher;

public class MyExtention implements TestWatcher, AfterEachCallback {


    @Override public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext context) {
        if (context.getElement().isPresent() && context.getElement().get().isAnnotationPresent(MyCustomAnnotation.class)) {
            int val = context.getElement().get().getAnnotation(MyCustomAnnotation.class).value();
            // Report on success
        }
    }

    @Override public void afterEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        if (context.getElement().isPresent() && context.getElement().get().isAnnotationPresent(MyCustomAnnotation.class)) {
            int val = context.getElement().get().getAnnotation(MyCustomAnnotation.class).value();
            // Report each
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alex, the following might be used inside the listener...
((MethodSource) testIdentifier.source).javaMethod.getAnnotation(TestCase.class)